# Set Transient does nothing

Tags: wp-query, transient

I'm trying to set a transient on my custom query, but it does not seem to work. Every time I refresh the page it still show me different posts each time.

After reading up on the transients api, I came to believe that setting a transient would store my first query with the exact same posts it queried and display them again next time without doing the whole query again.

Am I wrong or what am I doing wrong?

Here's my complete **UPDATED** query:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['myCookie']) && $_COOKIE['myCookie'] == $f_a){

// Check for transient. If none, then execute WP_Query
if ( false === ( $akerargs = get_transient( 'county_query' ) ) ) {

    $akerargs = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'nopaging' => false,
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'  => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Count',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $f_a,
        )
    )

);

// Put the results in a transient. Expire after 10 minutes.
set_transient( 'county_query', $akerargs, 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );

}

ob_start();?>

<div class="container-fluid">

<?php

$akerquery = new WP_Query( $akerargs );

?>

<div class="row">

<?php if ( $akerquery->have_posts() ) {

while ( $akerquery->have_posts() ) {
    $akerquery->the_post();
?>  

   <div class="col-6 mt-4">  

        <a href="<?php the_field('county_link'); ?> ">
                <img src="<?php echo the_field('county_img'); ?>" />
       </a>  

    </div> 

<?php

}

$akerquery->wp_reset_postdata();

} else {

echo 'Oops! Something went wrong.';

}

?>

</div>
</div>

<?php

return ob_get_clean();
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried multiple possible solutions to this now and it still does not work. According to the WordPress codex this is how it could be accomplished:

```
// Check for transient. If none, then execute WP_Query
if ( false === ( $featured = get_transient( 'foo_featured_posts' ) ) ) {

      $featured = new WP_Query(
       array(
        'category' => 'featured',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
       ));

    // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 12 hours.
    set_transient( 'foo_featured_posts', $featured, 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
} ?>

// Run the loop as normal
```

And this is what I've tried now:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['myCookie']) && $_COOKIE['myCookie'] == $f_a){

    // Check for transient. If none, then execute WP_Query
if ( false === ( $akerargs = get_transient( 'county_query' ) ) ) {


    $akerargs = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'nopaging' => false,
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'  => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Count',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $f_a,
        )
    )
);


$akerquery = new WP_Query( $akerargs );

    // Put the results in a transient. Expire after 10 minutes.
set_transient( 'county_query', $akerargs, 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
}
// Run the loop as normal
```

But it still runs the query and fetches new posts instead of saving the 4 posts that gets queried at first in the transient.

Comment: Hey Cap'n.  try setting some indents, and show us your whole code and I think you'll see quickly what krzysiek is saying.

Comment: Instead of setting your transient to be the actual query make your transient the results of the query

Comment: @rudtek I updated the question now, with the entire code for the query and output.

Comment: @rudtek, so basically what you are saying is that this `if ( false === ( $akerargs = get_transient( 'akershus_query' ) ) ) { $akerquery = new WP_Query( $akerargs ); set_transient( 'county_query', $akerargs, 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ); }` is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that exactly how it will work, because that’s what you coded ;)

You set the transient correctly, but...

You put only query arguments in there. And that doesn’t make much sense - it’s just an PHP array that is very easy and quick to create.

And the query itself is executed always - it’s outside the if. So yes - the results of the query are obtained on every request. And because you use `rand` as orderly, then you get random posts on every request.

If you want to use transients to cache results of query and display the same posts for 10 minutes (or other period), then you’ll have to keep these results in the transient.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer completely. You are saying that the transient I set is basically no good? What would i need to change to get it to work as intended? Which is to store the query for later use.

Comment: @SteveRodgers take a look at your code. What are you storing in transient? An array. And when are you querying posts? Always ;) So yes - you use transients and your code works exactly how it is written. You should store results of that query, not params, if you want it to work how you described.

Comment: Okay, I see. Will it work if I wrap the transient around `$akerquery = new WP_Query( $akerargs );` also, or do I have to wrap the entire loop and html output in the transient?

Comment: @SteveRodgers you have to wrap it all, but you also have to store correct data in transient... But I’m starting to repeat myself, I guess. I’ve explained it pretty clear in my answer.

Comment: I understand, and I've tried different possible solutions now with no luck still. I've updated my question with new information.

Comment: @SteveRodgers wow. And what have you changed? I still see clearly that you store $akerargs in transient - so you still put only array of args in there...

Comment: @SteveRodgers I’ll try to explain it later time with easier query. Let’s say you want to select all posts published before 2019-01-01. This query may take some time. So you want to perform it only once and store the results as transient. Storing only the string “2019-01-01” as transient won’t help you - right? Because you still have to perform the query each time. So what will help you? Performing the query and storing its results (found posts) in the transient. And all that time, your code is storing only query args as transient and the query is executed...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż.  You haven't provided an answer, but merely commentary

Comment: My mistake, changed from `set_transient( 'county_query', $akerargs, 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );` to `set_transient( 'county_query', $akerquery, 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );` now, and guess what? It works. As you already knew it would! Thank you for not throwing the answer in my face. I guess i understand it better now:)

Comment: @rudtek question was: why doesn’t it work like OP wanted - Ibe explained it pretty clear. So sorry - that’s the answer to why question.

Comment: @SteveRodgers exactly so. I’m glad it helped and now you understand the difference :)